# Google Sheets Automatic next cell activation

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a custom form in Google Sheets. The order of the data fields on the sheet form is different from the order that I would like to jump to (next cell) when the user presses [Enter] or [Tab] on the keyboard. Is there a method to use on the sheet (not using Google Apps Script) that I can prescribe for movement to the Next Cell.

Comment: you should share a simplified spreadsheet

Comment: there is no method that does not involve apps script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
function onEdit(event){ 
  var f = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var c = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (f.getName() == 'mySheet'){
    var adresses = ["E7","H7","E10","H10","E13","H13","E16"];
    var valeurs = adresses.join().split(",");
    var item = valeurs.indexOf(c.getA1Notation());
    if (item < adresses.length - 1){ // except the last one
      f.setActiveSelection(adresses[item + 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was afraid it was not possible without script.

Comment: Exactly! or may be as excel by protecting cells ?